# Possible for jQuery to add a css class to an image if it doesn't have one?

Tags: jquery, css, image, jquery-selectors

As title says, I have a div. Somewhere (could be embedded in further child divs) will be images. Is it possible to assign a style to all of the images in this div that do not currently have a style?

EDIT:

```
<div id="testDiv">
<div>
<img id="testImage1" class="testclass1"/>
<img id="testImage2" />
</div>
<span>
<img id="testImage3"/>
<img id="testImage4" class="testclass2"/>
</span>
</div>
```

testImage2 and testImage3 (above) will have a class of testclass3 assigned to it.

Comment: Are you wanting to add a different class to the images that dont have a class? If so is there a specific class that will be on the other images?

Comment: Be more specific and show us some code on what you are asking.

Comment: @Vega - I don't know how much more specific I can be. There is a div. Somewhere within that div (could be nested in an arbitrary amount of child elements) will be images, somewhere. I want to select them all. Those that do not have css classes I want to assign a particular class to.

Comment: @DeeMac I would post some code or an example of the scenario explained to get faster and best answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [:not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector to find the elements without a class and then use the [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) to add a class.

Try this:

```
$("img:not([class])").addClass("robasta");
```

NB: [I did a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P6Mg3/), but to see the result you have to Firebug through the results pane

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div').find('img[class=""]').addClass('yourClass');
```

Comment: @Vega - "...that do not currently have a style" (OP). Thanks a lot Andrea, problem solved I think, I'll give it a whirl.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#divid").find("img").each(function(index){
 if(undefined==$(this).attr("style")){
  // SET YOU STYLE HERE
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like below,

```
$(function() {
    $('#testDiv').find('img').filter(function (){        
        return this.className == '';  
    }).addClass('yourClass');
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/EXSUN/